# Causes of Dead Pixels in LCD

Tags: laptop, lcd

My laptop has three columns of dead pixels and it appears to be growing everyday. I myself came to accept it that the only remedy is to replace the screen. My question now, because I am still confused, is about specific causes of dead pixels. (Read: I have a nagger of an uncle and I have to have a defense in case my mother interrogated me about this freaking screen. Please do help me :))

Do old laptops tend to have greater risk of having dead pixels? My laptop is almost 8 years old now.

Does frequent use (Read: using the laptop for an extended duration of time-- eg 9-20 hours straight) cause dead pixels? I am annoyed by my uncle's ignorant assertion that my extended use is the primary cause of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: There is no specific cause.  Most of the time if its a couple pixels its simply a defect in the monitor.  If you drop a monitor then then thats an entirely another story.

Comment: I am pretty much sure that I haven't drop my laptop so imagine my surprise when these lines and spots started to appear.

Comment: Sometimes they just get tired of living..

Answer (score 1):

If it's an entire column of dead pixels it may be the connection between the laptop and motherboard is bad or needs to be reseated.  Also, dropping the laptop or other physical damage, such as liquids, could cause this.

I've never had a monitor or LCD develop bad pixels on its own.  At my workplace we have some laptops that are over 5 years old and none have spontaneously developed bad pixels.  The screen problems we typically see would be the entire screen or backlight going out.